# When using mice, I get Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:8: unexpected symbol

Tags: r, error-handling, data-analysis, data-cleaning, r-mice

When the `mice` package for missing value imputation, I get the following error:

```r
impute_vals = mice(cols, threshold = 1, m=1, maxit = 3, printFlag = TRUE)
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:8: unexpected symbol
1: Clicks per
       ^
```

All columns are numerical. I'm not sure why it is not letting me run the MICE imputations.

Comment: My guess is that the column names should be renamed to the one without spaces.

Comment: You are genius ~ Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I changed to column name and this worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31443431)